# Recursion Relation on Expected of Ehrenfest Chain

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

The expected value of an Ehrenfest Chain at state $X_{n+1}$ can be shown to be
$$E[X_{n+1}] = 1 + (1 - 2/M)E[X_n]$$
Using recursion, one can find the closed form solution of $E[X_n]$ which is done below.

\begin{align*}
E[X_n] &= 1 + \left(1 - \frac{2}{M}\right)E[X_{n-1}]\\
   &= 1 + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)E[X_{n-1}]\\
   &= 1 + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)\left[1 + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)E[X_{n-2}]\right]\\
   &= 1 + \frac{M-2}{M} + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^2E[X_{n-2}]\\
&= 1 + \frac{M-2}{M} + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^3E[X_{n-3}]\\
   &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^i + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^n E[X_0]\\
   &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^i - \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^n +  \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^n E[X_0]\\
   &= \frac{1}{1 - \frac{M-2}{M}} - \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^n +  \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^n E[X_0]\\
   &= \frac{M}{2} + \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^n\left[E[X_0] - 1\right]
\end{align*}

Here's the problem. I'm pretty sure that final term is supposed to be M/2 instead of 1, but that would require a geometric sum to be attached to the $-\left(\dfrac{M-2}{M}\right)^n$ term, but I'm not sure how that would happen. Was there an error made in the algebra?

Comment: Anyway... to solve this recursion, rewrite it as $$E(X_n)-M/2=(1-2/M)(E(X_{n-1}-M/2)$$ which yields instantly $$E(X_n)-M/2=(1-2/M)^n(E(X_0)-M/2)$$ hence indeed the $1$ in your last parenthesis should actually read $M/2$.

Comment: And it seems your solution uses the identity $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac{M-2}{M}\right)^i= \frac{1}{1 - \frac{M-2}{M}} $$ which is wrong.

Comment: Yea, I realize now that that is not a geometric series because a geometric series goes to infinity, not $n$.

Comment: Fixing the sum got me there. Thanks Did.